# deep-copied subclass of threading.local object throws TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given) when accessed in thread pool

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a code below that an object is a subclass of `threading.local`. This object is "deep-copied" before executed in another thread.

```
import copy
import functools
import sys
import threading
import traceback
from multiprocessing import dummy

# This decorator is purely for debugging purpose.
def get_traceback(f):
    @functools.wraps(f)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return f(*args, **kwargs)
        except Exception, ex:
            ret = '#' * 60
            ret += "\nException caught:"
            ret += "\n" + '-' * 60
            ret += "\n" + traceback.format_exc()
            ret += "\n" + '-' * 60
            ret += "\n" + "#" * 60
            print sys.stderr, ret
            sys.stderr.flush()
            raise ex

    return wrapper


@get_traceback
def func(o):
    print("Addr %s" % o.address)


class Server(threading.local):
    def __init__(self, address):
        self.address = address

# Initialize object.
server = Server("10.10.10.10")

# Make a deepcopy.
# Things work fine when this statement is removed, otherwise
# throws exception as described.
server = copy.deepcopy(server)

# Create pool, execute the function with deep-copied object.
thread_pool = dummy.Pool(1) 
try:
    thread_pool.map(func, [server])
except Exception as e:
    print('Caught exception in '
          'test: %s: %s' % (e.__class__, e))
    print(traceback.format_exc())
    raise e
finally:
    thread_pool.close()
    thread_pool.join()
```

Throws this exception within `copy.deepcopy(...)`
Note that `get_traceback(...)` decorator is purely for *debugging purpose*.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/hcho/PycharmProjects/test/file.py", line 13, in wrapper
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/hcho/PycharmProjects/test/file.py", line 30, in func
    print("Addr %s" % o.address)
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

The code works if I remove the `server = copy.deepcopy(server)` statement.

#### My guess

It seems that `deepcopy.copy(...)` makes new objects using `__dict__.update` such that `threading.local`'s `__setattr__(...)` isn't invoked, so something there is causing copied object to behave funky when accessed in another thread. Any thoughts?

Comment: Where is the line `copy.deepcopy(o)` in your code? The traceback suggests it should be in `func`, but it's not in the version of that function you've shown us. Are you sure you're posting the exact same code that is giving you the error?

Comment: @Blckknght, Sorry, I've made the changes.